# Finding the word in every line c#

Tags: c#, text, output, lines

so I'm writing a program that takes in a text line by line and then is supposed to output yes or no if the line contains the word problem.
The program is working, but I have to press enter twice to get the output.
The first enter I get, which is for the last line. And the second enter is so the while loop can break out.

Any suggestions to how I can improve this and not need the second enter?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Tester
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
            string input = "";
            while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != string.Empty)
            {
                var s = input.ToLower();
                stringList.Add(s.Contains("problem") ? "yes" : "no");
            }

            foreach (var str in stringList)
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How else would you indicate the end of all input? Press `Ctrl+Z` instead of `[Enter]` after the last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the last output you will type something. That's when `(input = Console.ReadLine()) != string.Empty` kicks in and the condition will pass.

The loop will come back to this line and block until you give it new input. Then supposedly you just type enter and in that case the loop will just exist. This is expected behaviour.

I'm not sure what upsets you about this. If you reaaaally wanted to get rid of the second enter, maybe you can put some token in your line (line `/q` or whatever) and whenever that is found in your line you know that you should break out of the loop.

Alternatively you can count how many inputs you get and make sure you get exactly `10` or `20` or whatever. When that number is reached, the loop will exit after the last input is processed.

Comment: The assignment is to input a text and find the word problem in every line, then output the yes and no for each line all at once and not efter every readline :)

Comment: I don't think that comment was meant for me :P In any case, I see no problem having to press enter twice - that's normal behaviour. Shaamaan provided some tips about running it in the console or setting up VS to run it as you want, but otherwise I don't see any problem with your current situation :P

Comment: Yeah it wasn't, my bad :P

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. :)

You can safely get rid of the last `ReadKey`. Given that you're creating a console application, you would normally rut it... in a console - as such, consoles don't close themselves after a program is done running. It's different if you run a console application in Windows OUTSIDE of a console - in this case, Windows will open a temporary console, run the app, and then close the console.

Also, if you're using Visual Studio, you can make VS wait for you by using the "start without debug" option (Ctrl+F5). VS will then add a "press enter to close" on it's own, at the end, to prevent the window from closing too fast, allowing you to check your outputs / exceptions.

One simple solution could be to output the "yes" or "no" values per line, rather than all at once at the end of your app.

Another way (which would require a bit more coding) would be to read individual keys, rather than lines - then you could react to the user pressing Esc, for example, rather than relying on an empty string ("extra" enter press).

Comment: He's probably running it in VS :P

Comment: @async I know - but it's the point of the application he has to consider. As for running it inside VS - I've added a trick that should help him. :)

Comment: @Shaamaan The ReadKey is only so I can see that the output works :P I just forgot to remove it when I posted the question :) Now I know about the start without debugging, thx! 
The assignment is to output the yes o no all at once, otherwise I would have done it that way.

Comment: @Yaner Well, the person checking your assignment (assuming they know what they're doing), should know better than to run a console application straight from Windows, so... yeah. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` and `ToUpper()` method is in general more accurate than `ToLower()`. So i'd probably refactor your code to something like :

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
        string input = "";

        while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input = Console.ReadLine()))
            stringList.Add(input.ToUpper().Contains("PROBLEM") ? "yes" : "no");

        foreach (var str in stringList)
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

By the way welcome to SO... ;)

Answer (score 0):

ok,do you mean this

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "";
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        while (input != string.Empty)
        {
            if (input.Contains("problem"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("yes");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no");
            }
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

maybe I know your intention.But if you want to break the while(input!=string.Empty) you must press an empty line.

Comment: I'll try it! 
The output is supposed to be yes or no all at once, not after efter input line :)